# Design pattern for related base classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, design-patterns, type-hinting

I am currently developing a new driver system for physical experiments. The system will consist of several drivers for electronical instruments that can be very different from each other. But all drivers are made up mutliple channels, that are used for different things.

To keep the system uniform, I decided to define base classes for the driver and for the channels. Let us call them `DriverBase` and `ChannelBase`. All driver implementations are based on these base classes.

For example: To develop a driver for instrument XY, one needs to implement the classes `XYDriver` and `XYChannel` and for the instrument AB the classes `ABDriver` and `ABChannel` are needed.
To make the system foolproof I want to use *type hints*, so nobody would try to use incompatible types. So the base classes would look like this:

```
class DriverBase:
    def __init__(self):
        # This list needs to be type-hinted, so the derived class only accepts a
        # specific channel-type, that is related to this specific driver
        # implementation. If the subclass tries to append another channel-type
        # than expected, the user should be informed about this.
        self._channels: List[ChannelBase] = [] 

    # The users should know, what is returned by this property as exactly as
    # possible.
    @property
    def channels(self) -> ChannelBase:
        return self._channels

class ChannelBase:
    def __init__(self, parent: DriverBase):
        self._parent = parent

    # The users should know, what is returned by this property as exactly as
    # possible.
    @property
    def parent_device(self) -> DriverBase:
        return self._parent

# The subclasses should be as simple as possible, because those are
# implemented by the users themselves.

class XYChannel(ChannelBase):
    # ...
class ABChannel(ChannelBase):
    # ...

class XYDriver(DriverBase):
    def __init__(self, channel_count: int):
        super().__init__()
        # This is how it should be used
        for i in range(channel_count):
            self._channels.append(XYChannel(i))

class ABDriver(DriverBase):
    def __init__(self, channel_count: int):
        super().__init__()
        # Here a user made a typical copy-paste-mistake. Maybe the channels
        # of both devices are very similar so that the script will terminate
        # without any error, but the instrument channels did not get any
        # data. So it would be very nice, if the IDE automatically warns the
        # user, that this type is not allowed.
        for i in range(channel_count):
            self._channels.append(XYChannel(i)) # ABChannel would be correct
```

Now I can be sure that a `DriverBase` has a list of `ChannelBase`s and each `ChannelBase` has a `DriverBase` as parent object. This works pretty fine and my IDE will remind me, if something is wrong implemented.
But because I want to make the system foolproof and I am little perfectionist, I want to keep this behaiviour in the subclasses, too, without redefining the `channels` and `parent_device` properties, because there are actually some more than those two properties. I need to prevent the users from mixing up the subclasses, like using `XYChannel`s in `ABDriver`s or `ABChannel`s in `XYDriver`s, as seen in `ABDriver`. This is what I want to avoid. The easiest way is to make those properties abstract and force the users to make new *type hints* in the overridden properties. But this is not what I want... I am searching for a solution that is completely located in the base classes. I hope there is some kind of design pattern, that holds relating classes together and prevents them from interacting with classes outside this relations.

Do you guys have any idea about this? I hope someone understands what I mean, because it seems to be very specific and it is really hard to explain for me.

Thanks in advance.

---

**Update**

The idea behind this question is the following. My users (physicists and technicians) use my driver framework to automate their measurements and they will also develop their own drivers. I will make the framework as foolproof as possible, with custom exceptions and type/value-checks for all user provided parameters. But this is not the case... What I want is not a must-have. But it would be very nice, if the users would receive warnings while writing their code. So they do not have to wait until they can test their code to know if it is working.

Answer (score 1):

are your users going to write the code?? You already defined the interface in your base class, not sure what you are trying to achieve exactly, but you can add checks of the kind isinstance() in

```
for i in range(channel_count):
    if not isinstance(ChannelBase, XYChannel(i)):
        raise IncompatibleChannelException('your message here')

    self._channels.append(XYChannel(i))
```

(Same in the other one but swapping the classes). Or as you say make them abstract so they know they are implementing the right class.
If you want to follow this suggestion, you can add a specific method to typecheck on initialization (called during **init** execution).

Something like;

```
    def __init__(self, channel_class):
        # This list needs to be type-hinted, so the derived class only accepts a
        # specific channel-type, that is related to this specific driver
        # implementation. If the subclass tries to append another channel-type
        # than expected, the user should be informed about this.
        self._channels: List[ChannelBase] = [] 
        self.channel_class = channel_class
        self.type_check_on_init()
        for i in range(channel_count):
            self._channels.append(self.channel_class(i))

    def type_check_on_init(self):
        if not isinstance(ChannelBase, self.channel_class):
            raise IncompatibleChannelException('Channel must be of type {} not {}'.format(ChannelBase, self.channel_class)
```

If ABDriver always works with ABChannel, you can make them abstract properties of the class and force people to implement them:

```
class DriverBase:
    def __init__(self):
        # This list needs to be type-hinted, so the derived class only accepts a
        # specific channel-type, that is related to this specific driver
        # implementation. If the subclass tries to append another channel-type
        # than expected, the user should be informed about this.
        self._channels: List[ChannelBase] = [] 

    # The users should know, what is returned by this property as exactly as
    # possible.
    @abc.abstractproperty
    def channel_class(self):
        pass
```

that way every subclass is forced to specify a channel class that they can implement

Comment: Yes, my users will write code. Because I am just providing an driver framework. The users are physicists and technicians. They use this framework to automate their measurements and data analyses.
I will use type checks with isinstance (or issubclass, ...) in my classes as well. But what I need is a way to check the types before runtime, so the IDE can show warnings before executing the code. The only way to do something like this in Python are those type hints, as far as I know. But maybe there are some other solutions, like doc strings or so, that can be interpreted by the IDE.